# Java: Symbol not found, Maven Package

Tags: java, maven

I am using an API that uses Maven & JitPack repositories, but there's a problem. Everytime I load my Java project, it brings up an error:

[image]

Here's the script:

```java
package com.anas.alqurancloudapi;
import com.anas.alqurancloudapi.*;
public class Testing {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Ayah v_ = Ayah.getAyah(1);
        System.out.println(v_.toString());
        
    }    
}
```

Here's the XML Script:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <groupId>com.mycompany.app</groupId>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <artifactId>my-app</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>jitpack.io</id>
            <url>https://jitpack.io</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.anas-elgarhy</groupId>
            <artifactId>alquran-cloud-api</artifactId>
            <version>0.4.2-v1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Comment: Where is this `Ayah` class declared?

Comment: It's in the package

Comment: Please show some minimal code for that class and explain the steps you take that cause the error? Is this when you compile your package? Or when you try to use it in another project?

Comment: Remove `import com.anas.alqurancloudapi.*;` (because it's current package)

Comment: My bad guys, I'm trying to import a package, not create one

Answer (score 1):

Seems you are importing from the same path as your package. Try changing your package name.

Comment: How do I do that?

Comment: It depends on which IDE you use, you can search for that, it spouse be simple